# Grafana throws 'Templating init failed' error after upgrade when using graphite backend

Tags: graphite, grafana

I'm trying to upgrade my Grafana setup from version `v4.0.2 (commit: v4.0.2)` to version `v4.4.3 (commit: 54c79c5)` on CentOS 7. Both old and new versions of Grafana are installed from official RPM packages.

When I'm trying to open any dashboard that I have I'm getting a following error message:

```
Templating init failed
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Also in the browser console log I see the following messages:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (<anonymous>)
at String.replace (<anonymous>)
at Object.replace (http://<my_grafana_host>/public/app/boot.07485e0c.js:10:23129)
at Object.get (http://<my_grafana_host>/public/app/boot.07485e0c.js:45:5205)
at Object.get (http://<my_grafana_host>/public/app/boot.07485e0c.js:45:5235)
at Object.get (http://<my_grafana_host>/public/app/boot.07485e0c.js:45:5235)
at Object.get (http://<my_grafana_host>/public/app/boot.07485e0c.js:45:5235)
at Object.get (http://<my_grafana_host>/public/app/boot.07485e0c.js:45:5235)
at Object.get (http://<my_grafana_host>/public/app/boot.07485e0c.js:45:5235) <plugin-component type="query-ctrl">
```

I'm getting the same error in browser console when I'm trying to `Save & Test` settings in Graphite datasource. In this case I'm seeing a progress bar that says `Testing...` but never completes.

I've checked behaviour in Chrome and Firefox and it breaks in the same way in both browsers.

I've double-checked and graphite is up and running and is listening on the selected URL. Also when I'm trying to revert the change and run Grafana 4.0.2 it does work with the same settings.

I've also tried to run new Grafana with default configuration coming from RPM with no luck.

I know that's not much information and I would be glad to provide any additional info that might help resolving this issue.

Comment: Same issue, but seems to be floating.

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing similar issue?